# writing a constraint for a maximisation problem

Tags: optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

There are $n$ seats in a row. $p$ people (where $p<n$) can seat anywhere as long as long as they sit at least one seat apart due to personal relationships.

This statement is part of a larger problem related to optimisation. Can you give insights how to write this statement as a constraint? I am struggling to find a way to write it nicely in a constraint form, so I am ready for optimisation.

Insights appreciated

Comment: In your larger problem, do you need to distinguish people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_i$ for i=1,..,n be a binary variable, which is 1 if seat i is occupied, and 0 if it is not.

$x_i + x_{i+1} \le 1$, for i=1,..,n-1 precludes 2 people sitting next to each other.

$\Sigma_{i=1}^n x_i = p$ if you want to make sure everyone is seated somewhere.

If it is impossible to satisfy both these constraints, the problem will be infeasible.  This would happen if $p > \lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: Thanks. By brute force, we can easily see that $p \leq \lceil n/2 \rceil$ is the optimum value. Any analytical solution to this?

Comment: You haven't told us what the entirety of the problem is. I merely showed you how to express the constraints you inquired about.

Answer (score 0):

Hi: If $a_i$ = 1 when you sit there and zero when you don't. Then the constraint is $abs((a_{i+1} - a_{i})) > 0$. Not sure if that helps because it involves integer programming but maybe you can modify as necessary. Note that this type of constraint won't allow for two empty seats in a row.

Comment: What you propose is equivalent to $a_{i+1}\not=a_i$, which is too strong because it prohibits $a_{i+1}=a_i=0$.

Comment: Thanks RobPratt. I tried to say that in the last sentence but I guess it wasn't clear. I was kind of hoping that the constraints might be such that two empty seats in a row might not be possible. But, you are correct. As it stands, my constraint doesn't allow for two empty seats in a row which could be a problem. Thanks again.

Comment: What Mark Stone suggested is better than what I suggested.